# generating moment and expecting value

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Let X and Y be independent geometric random variables with parameter p and let $Z=E(X|X+Y)$.

1. Compute the moment generating function $M_X$ of X.
2. Compute the moment generating function $M_{X+Y}$ of $X+Y$.
3. Compute $E(Z)$.
4. Compute $Var(Z)$.

For 1. I got $M_x=pe^t/((1-e^t(1-p))$
2. $M_{X+Y}$ of $X+Y$ is $M_x(t)M_y(t)$ as they are independent so I just need $M_y$ that is the same as in case 1, right?

3. I don't know what means $Z=E(X|X+Y)$, is just $X+Y$?
   Thanks

Comment: no, $Z$ is a conditional expectation, its a very different thing but it is also a random variable. It is the unique r.v. that is $\sigma(X+Y)$ measurable and $$\int_C E[X|X+Y]dP=\int_C X dP$$ for all $C\in\sigma(X+Y)$

Answer (score 1):

$E(X|X+Y)=E(Y|X+Y)$ since $X,Y$ are i.i.d. Adding these two we get $1$. Hence, $Z=E(X|X+Y)=\frac  1 2$ and $EZ =\frac 1  2, var (Z)=0$.